# Перекодировка и сразу транслит

Tags: c#, кодировка

Здравствуйте! Есть ли такая возможность в C# на лету перекодировать строку из существующей кодировки(нечитаемой) в utf-8 и затем (в моем случае кирилицу) транслировать в латинский?

То есть из такого :

> **`"Р”Р»СЏ РљР°С‡Р°РЅРіРё"`**

получается такое:

> **то что надо**

а затем :

> **to chto nado**

Answer (score 8):

В .NET у строк нет кодировки. Они всегда должны быть правильными by design.

Если у вас есть массив байт, вы можете интерпретировать его как текст в любой кодировке по вашему желанию, и превратить в строку. Так что первая часть вопроса не особо релевантна: скорее всего в том месте, где вы получаете данные, вы конвертируете их в строку неправильно.

Насчёт перекодировки в транслит, проще всего сделать через таблицу, это позволит вам применять те правила, которые вы считаете верными:

```
static Dictionary<char, string> translation = new Dictionary<char, string>()
{
    { 'а', "a" },
    { 'б', "b" },
    { 'в', "v" },
    { 'г', "g" },
    ...
    { 'я', "ya" },
    { 'А', "A" },
    ...
};

string ToTranslit(char c)
{
    string result;
    if (translation.TryGetValue(c, out result))
        return result;
    else
        return c.ToString();
}

string ToTranslit(string src)
{
    return string.Join(src.Select(ToTranslit));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Насчет транслита решение интересное,буду пробовать. А вот по первой части.Посмотрел внимательнее свой текстовый файл.Там из 4000 строк есть куски в одной кодировке, другие куски в другой..Так что NotePad++ переводит одну часть в читаемый по-русски вид, а другая становится нечитаемая. Получается этот конфиг железки в разное время и из разных редакторов заливали, так что так и получилось. команда StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(opendialog.FileName,Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8")); также не помогла. надо будет отдельно каждый кусок вырывать и декодировать.

Comment: Или самому написать программу, которая определяет кодировку куска и правильно перекодирует в utf-8.
(IMHO довольно интересная развлекуха).

Comment: @vlazarev: Ага. понимаю. То есть у вас на самом деле в файле куски в разной кодировке. К сожалению, автоматически раскодировать не получится. Если вы знаете, где границы разных кусков, попробуйте прочитать файл как массив символов, разбить на строки (по CR/LF/CRLF), и для каждой строки попробовать, успешно ли декодирование в одной из интересующих вас кодовых страниц (koi8-r, cp1251, cyr-alt=cp866), если да, можно считать декодировку удавшейся.

Comment: @vlazarev: Кстати, FAR, например, умеет угадывать кодовую страницу текста, используя частотный анализ. У него есть таблицы частот букв среднего русского текста, он вычисляет таблицы частот раскодированного текста в разных кодировках и выбирает ту, которая наиболее близка. Но это, конечно, эвристика, гарантии нету.

Comment: Конечно, без гарантий. 

Для короткого текста (однобайтного, с utf и др. кодировками юникода проще), ясно, почти невозможно отличить "мама" от "папа" (не придирайтесь, думаю суть ясна), а на десятках букв статистика языка обычно уже работает нормально.

Кстати, Firefox (и наверное другие браузеры) тоже умеет автоопределять кодировку (но не для кусков текста!!!).

Вот сделать для кусков (тем более для смеси  внутри одной строки) -- это была бы интересная задачка. Наверное тут надо заниматься уже криптоанализом.

Comment: @avp: Я думаю, в рамках обсуждаемой задачи можно смело предположить, что

* в пределах одной строки кодировка постоянна
* кодировки соседних строк с большой вероятностью совпадают

Правда, понятие «строки» в условиях неопределённой кодировки получается размытым (может ли многобайтный символ в кодировке переменной длины заканчиваться на `\x0a`? в UCS-4 конец строки есть `\x00\x00\x00\x0a` + варианты с `\x0d` и т. д.)

Comment: @VladD, думаю, что практически данная задача 

    ... свой текстовый файл.Там из 4000 строк ...

 решается вооруженными редактором и iconv руками за пару часов.

--

А понятие строки вообще контекстно-зависимое. Например, в CSV формате (тоже ведь текстовый файл) `\n` внутри строкового поля, взятого в кавычки, должен рассматриватья как часть этого поля, а не разделитель записей CSV-файла.

Если же смотреть на бесформатный текст, то думаю, что конец строки надо определять по текущей (той что мы в этом месте считаем правильной) кодировке куска (т.е. по сути, после перекодировки).

Comment: @avp: так и есть. Проблема в том, что для того, чтобы определить кодировку куска, нужно бы сначала определить границы этого куска и провести на них частотный анализ. Но для определения границ в свою очередь нужно знать текущую кодировку. Есть ли простой очевидный выход, без эвристик? (Эвристикой может быть, например, «считать концом строки всё, что им может быть в какой-нибудь кодировке». Но эта эвристика может разрезать многобайтный символ.)